# The procedure entry point axiom_attribute_create could not be located in the dynamic link library

Tags: c, linker, entry-point, stdcall, axis2c

I have a project in c and I want to compile it in CodeBlocks with MinGW.
I tried to link its needed libraries but I got

> undefined reference error

so I searched and found out that the libraries that I was using was compiled with MVC++ and cannot be used with MinGW. (I am not an expert in c, so I'm a little bit confused.) I found [This](https://www.daniweb.com/software-development/cpp/threads/260792/linker-error-undefined-reference-to-_imp__axutil_env_create_all#post1133608) link and did what they said in order to solve my problem.

I have created axis2c .a files from the original axis2c .dll files.

- I created .def files with reimp
- then I modified each stdcall function in .def files (I changed "_name@ordinal" to "name")
- then I used dlltool to create .a files.

I linked the .a files to my project. Everything went fine and I could compile my project. but when I try to run it. I get this error.

> The procedure entry point axiom_attribute_create could not be located in the dynamic link library

I have included my project in this [Link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/b8ivo6m5xrwcocs/Math.rar?dl=0).

**I downloaded a CodeBlocks with MinGW.** codeblocks-10.05mingw-setup.exe (which I guess uses **MinGw32bit**).Then I followed the steps that @mikekinghan said to set up **Build Options**. Then I built the project. I got this error.
I have already added Axis2c lib folder to path Environment. (I even copied axiom.dll to "C:\Windows\SysWOW64" as @mikekinghan suggested.

Here is the build log :

```
-------------- Build: Debug in Math ---------------

mingw32-gcc.exe -Wall  -g    -IC:\Tools\axis2c\include -IE:\dev\CodeBlocks\MinGW  -c E:\dev\c\Math\adb_addOperatorResponse.c -o obj\Debug\adb_addOperatorResponse.o
In file included from C:\Tools\axis2c\include/platforms/axutil_platform_auto_sense.h:40,
                 from C:\Tools\axis2c\include/axutil_dll_desc.h:31,
                 from C:\Tools\axis2c\include/axutil_class_loader.h:31,
                 from C:\Tools\axis2c\include/axis2_util.h:24,
                 from E:\dev\c\Math\adb_addOperatorResponse.h:21,
                 from E:\dev\c\Math\adb_addOperatorResponse.c:10:
C:\Tools\axis2c\include/platforms/windows/axutil_windows.h:221:5: warning: "/*" within comment
E:\dev\c\Math\adb_addOperatorResponse.c: In function 'adb_addOperatorResponse_serialize_obj':
E:\dev\c\Math\adb_addOperatorResponse.c:466: warning: format '%I32d' expects type 'long int', but argument 3 has type 'int'
E:\dev\c\Math\adb_addOperatorResponse.c:374: warning: unused variable 'ns_already_defined'
E:\dev\c\Math\adb_addOperatorResponse.c:372: warning: unused variable 'qname_prefix'
E:\dev\c\Math\adb_addOperatorResponse.c:371: warning: unused variable 'qname_uri'
E:\dev\c\Math\adb_addOperatorResponse.c:367: warning: unused variable 'tag_closed'
E:\dev\c\Math\adb_addOperatorResponse.c: In function 'adb_addOperatorResponse_reset_addOperatorReturn':
E:\dev\c\Math\adb_addOperatorResponse.c:568: warning: unused variable 'element'
E:\dev\c\Math\adb_addOperatorResponse.c:567: warning: unused variable 'count'
E:\dev\c\Math\adb_addOperatorResponse.c:566: warning: unused variable 'i'
mingw32-gcc.exe -Wall  -g    -IC:\Tools\axis2c\include -IE:\dev\CodeBlocks\MinGW  -c E:\dev\c\Math\axis2_extension_mapper.c -o obj\Debug\axis2_extension_mapper.o
In file included from C:\Tools\axis2c\include/platforms/axutil_platform_auto_sense.h:40,
                 from C:\Tools\axis2c\include/axutil_dll_desc.h:31,
                 from C:\Tools\axis2c\include/axutil_class_loader.h:31,
                 from C:\Tools\axis2c\include/axis2_util.h:24,
                 from E:\dev\c\Math\axis2_extension_mapper.h:14,
                 from E:\dev\c\Math\axis2_extension_mapper.c:10:
C:\Tools\axis2c\include/platforms/windows/axutil_windows.h:221:5: warning: "/*" within comment
E:\dev\c\Math\axis2_extension_mapper.c: In function 'axis2_extension_mapper_type_from_node':
E:\dev\c\Math\axis2_extension_mapper.c:31: warning: unused variable 'element_qname'
mingw32-gcc.exe -Wall  -g    -IC:\Tools\axis2c\include -IE:\dev\CodeBlocks\MinGW  -c E:\dev\c\Math\axis2_stub_MathService.c -o obj\Debug\axis2_stub_MathService.o
In file included from C:\Tools\axis2c\include/platforms/axutil_platform_auto_sense.h:40,
                 from C:\Tools\axis2c\include/axutil_dll_desc.h:31,
                 from C:\Tools\axis2c\include/axutil_class_loader.h:31,
                 from C:\Tools\axis2c\include/axis2_util.h:24,
                 from C:\Tools\axis2c\include/neethi_includes.h:22,
                 from C:\Tools\axis2c\include/neethi_operator.h:29,
                 from C:\Tools\axis2c\include/neethi_policy.h:29,
                 from C:\Tools\axis2c\include/axis2_svc_client.h:56,
                 from C:\Tools\axis2c\include/axis2_stub.h:35,
                 from C:\Tools\axis2c\include/axis2_client.h:31,
                 from E:\dev\c\Math\axis2_stub_MathService.h:14,
                 from E:\dev\c\Math\axis2_stub_MathService.c:10:
C:\Tools\axis2c\include/platforms/windows/axutil_windows.h:221:5: warning: "/*" within comment
E:\dev\c\Math\axis2_stub_MathService.c: In function 'axis2_stub_populate_services_for_MathService':
E:\dev\c\Math\axis2_stub_MathService.c:72: warning: unused variable 'status'
E:\dev\c\Math\axis2_stub_MathService.c:71: warning: unused variable 'neethi_policy'
E:\dev\c\Math\axis2_stub_MathService.c:70: warning: unused variable 'policy_root_ele'
E:\dev\c\Math\axis2_stub_MathService.c:69: warning: unused variable 'policy_node'
E:\dev\c\Math\axis2_stub_MathService.c:68: warning: unused variable 'desc'
E:\dev\c\Math\axis2_stub_MathService.c:66: warning: unused variable 'policy_include'
E:\dev\c\Math\axis2_stub_MathService.c: In function 'axis2_stub_on_complete_MathService_addOperator':
E:\dev\c\Math\axis2_stub_MathService.c:277: warning: unused variable 'soap_fault'
mingw32-gcc.exe -Wall  -g    -IC:\Tools\axis2c\include -IE:\dev\CodeBlocks\MinGW  -c E:\dev\c\Math\main.c -o obj\Debug\main.o
In file included from C:\Tools\axis2c\include/platforms/axutil_platform_auto_sense.h:40,
                 from C:\Tools\axis2c\include/axutil_dll_desc.h:31,
                 from C:\Tools\axis2c\include/axutil_class_loader.h:31,
                 from C:\Tools\axis2c\include/axis2_util.h:24,
                 from C:\Tools\axis2c\include/neethi_includes.h:22,
                 from C:\Tools\axis2c\include/neethi_operator.h:29,
                 from C:\Tools\axis2c\include/neethi_policy.h:29,
                 from C:\Tools\axis2c\include/axis2_svc_client.h:56,
                 from C:\Tools\axis2c\include/axis2_stub.h:35,
                 from C:\Tools\axis2c\include/axis2_client.h:31,
                 from E:\dev\c\Math\axis2_stub_MathService.h:14,
                 from E:\dev\c\Math\main.c:1:
C:\Tools\axis2c\include/platforms/windows/axutil_windows.h:221:5: warning: "/*" within comment
E:\dev\c\Math\main.c:3: warning: second argument of 'main' should be 'char **'
E:\dev\c\Math\main.c: In function 'main':
E:\dev\c\Math\main.c:8: warning: unused variable 'operation'
mingw32-gcc.exe -Wall  -g    -IC:\Tools\axis2c\include -IE:\dev\CodeBlocks\MinGW  -c E:\dev\c\Math\adb_addOperator.c -o obj\Debug\adb_addOperator.o
In file included from C:\Tools\axis2c\include/platforms/axutil_platform_auto_sense.h:40,
                 from C:\Tools\axis2c\include/axutil_dll_desc.h:31,
                 from C:\Tools\axis2c\include/axutil_class_loader.h:31,
                 from C:\Tools\axis2c\include/axis2_util.h:24,
                 from E:\dev\c\Math\adb_addOperator.h:21,
                 from E:\dev\c\Math\adb_addOperator.c:10:
C:\Tools\axis2c\include/platforms/windows/axutil_windows.h:221:5: warning: "/*" within comment
E:\dev\c\Math\adb_addOperator.c: In function 'adb_addOperator_serialize_obj':
E:\dev\c\Math\adb_addOperator.c:574: warning: format '%I32d' expects type 'long int', but argument 3 has type 'int'
E:\dev\c\Math\adb_addOperator.c:640: warning: format '%I32d' expects type 'long int', but argument 3 has type 'int'
E:\dev\c\Math\adb_addOperator.c:480: warning: unused variable 'ns_already_defined'
E:\dev\c\Math\adb_addOperator.c:478: warning: unused variable 'qname_prefix'
E:\dev\c\Math\adb_addOperator.c:477: warning: unused variable 'qname_uri'
E:\dev\c\Math\adb_addOperator.c:473: warning: unused variable 'tag_closed'
E:\dev\c\Math\adb_addOperator.c: In function 'adb_addOperator_reset_num1':
E:\dev\c\Math\adb_addOperator.c:742: warning: unused variable 'element'
E:\dev\c\Math\adb_addOperator.c:741: warning: unused variable 'count'
E:\dev\c\Math\adb_addOperator.c:740: warning: unused variable 'i'
E:\dev\c\Math\adb_addOperator.c: In function 'adb_addOperator_reset_num2':
E:\dev\c\Math\adb_addOperator.c:848: warning: unused variable 'element'
E:\dev\c\Math\adb_addOperator.c:847: warning: unused variable 'count'
E:\dev\c\Math\adb_addOperator.c:846: warning: unused variable 'i'
mingw32-g++.exe -LC:\Tools\axis2c\include -LE:\dev\CodeBlocks\MinGW\lib  -o bin\Debug\Math.exe obj\Debug\adb_addOperatorResponse.o obj\Debug\axis2_extension_mapper.o obj\Debug\axis2_stub_MathService.o obj\Debug\main.o obj\Debug\adb_addOperator.o   -laxiom -laxutil -laxis2_engine -laxis2_parser  
e:/dev/codeblocks/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.4.1/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -laxiom
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
Process terminated with status 1 (0 minutes, 6 seconds)
1 errors, 35 warnings
```

It seems that I made a mistake putting ../include in **Search Directories>Linker** I fixed that mistake.

[image]
[image]
[image]

I build the project then I get this :

```
-------------- Build: Debug in Math ---------------

mingw32-gcc.exe -Wall  -g    -IC:\Tools\axis2c\include -IE:\dev\CodeBlocks\MinGW  -c E:\dev\c\Math\adb_addOperatorResponse.c -o obj\Debug\adb_addOperatorResponse.o
In file included from C:\Tools\axis2c\include/platforms/axutil_platform_auto_sense.h:40,
                 from C:\Tools\axis2c\include/axutil_dll_desc.h:31,
                 from C:\Tools\axis2c\include/axutil_class_loader.h:31,
                 from C:\Tools\axis2c\include/axis2_util.h:24,
                 from E:\dev\c\Math\adb_addOperatorResponse.h:21,
                 from E:\dev\c\Math\adb_addOperatorResponse.c:10:
C:\Tools\axis2c\include/platforms/windows/axutil_windows.h:221:5: warning: "/*" within comment
E:\dev\c\Math\adb_addOperatorResponse.c: In function 'adb_addOperatorResponse_serialize_obj':
E:\dev\c\Math\adb_addOperatorResponse.c:466: warning: format '%I32d' expects type 'long int', but argument 3 has type 'int'
mingw32-gcc.exe -Wall  -g    -IC:\Tools\axis2c\include -IE:\dev\CodeBlocks\MinGW  -c E:\dev\c\Math\axis2_extension_mapper.c -o obj\Debug\axis2_extension_mapper.o
In file included from C:\Tools\axis2c\include/platforms/axutil_platform_auto_sense.h:40,
                 from C:\Tools\axis2c\include/axutil_dll_desc.h:31,
                 from C:\Tools\axis2c\include/axutil_class_loader.h:31,
                 from C:\Tools\axis2c\include/axis2_util.h:24,
                 from E:\dev\c\Math\axis2_extension_mapper.h:14,
                 from E:\dev\c\Math\axis2_extension_mapper.c:10:
C:\Tools\axis2c\include/platforms/windows/axutil_windows.h:221:5: warning: "/*" within comment
mingw32-gcc.exe -Wall  -g    -IC:\Tools\axis2c\include -IE:\dev\CodeBlocks\MinGW  -c E:\dev\c\Math\axis2_stub_MathService.c -o obj\Debug\axis2_stub_MathService.o
In file included from C:\Tools\axis2c\include/platforms/axutil_platform_auto_sense.h:40,
                 from C:\Tools\axis2c\include/axutil_dll_desc.h:31,
                 from C:\Tools\axis2c\include/axutil_class_loader.h:31,
                 from C:\Tools\axis2c\include/axis2_util.h:24,
                 from C:\Tools\axis2c\include/neethi_includes.h:22,
                 from C:\Tools\axis2c\include/neethi_operator.h:29,
                 from C:\Tools\axis2c\include/neethi_policy.h:29,
                 from C:\Tools\axis2c\include/axis2_svc_client.h:56,
                 from C:\Tools\axis2c\include/axis2_stub.h:35,
                 from C:\Tools\axis2c\include/axis2_client.h:31,
                 from E:\dev\c\Math\axis2_stub_MathService.h:14,
                 from E:\dev\c\Math\axis2_stub_MathService.c:10:
C:\Tools\axis2c\include/platforms/windows/axutil_windows.h:221:5: warning: "/*" within comment
mingw32-gcc.exe -Wall  -g    -IC:\Tools\axis2c\include -IE:\dev\CodeBlocks\MinGW  -c E:\dev\c\Math\main.c -o obj\Debug\main.o
In file included from C:\Tools\axis2c\include/platforms/axutil_platform_auto_sense.h:40,
                 from C:\Tools\axis2c\include/axutil_dll_desc.h:31,
                 from C:\Tools\axis2c\include/axutil_class_loader.h:31,
                 from C:\Tools\axis2c\include/axis2_util.h:24,
                 from C:\Tools\axis2c\include/neethi_includes.h:22,
                 from C:\Tools\axis2c\include/neethi_operator.h:29,
                 from C:\Tools\axis2c\include/neethi_policy.h:29,
                 from C:\Tools\axis2c\include/axis2_svc_client.h:56,
                 from C:\Tools\axis2c\include/axis2_stub.h:35,
                 from C:\Tools\axis2c\include/axis2_client.h:31,
                 from E:\dev\c\Math\axis2_stub_MathService.h:14,
                 from E:\dev\c\Math\main.c:1:
C:\Tools\axis2c\include/platforms/windows/axutil_windows.h:221:5: warning: "/*" within comment
E:\dev\c\Math\main.c:3: warning: second argument of 'main' should be 'char **'
mingw32-gcc.exe -Wall  -g    -IC:\Tools\axis2c\include -IE:\dev\CodeBlocks\MinGW  -c E:\dev\c\Math\adb_addOperator.c -o obj\Debug\adb_addOperator.o
In file included from C:\Tools\axis2c\include/platforms/axutil_platform_auto_sense.h:40,
                 from C:\Tools\axis2c\include/axutil_dll_desc.h:31,
                 from C:\Tools\axis2c\include/axutil_class_loader.h:31,
                 from C:\Tools\axis2c\include/axis2_util.h:24,
                 from E:\dev\c\Math\adb_addOperator.h:21,
                 from E:\dev\c\Math\adb_addOperator.c:10:
C:\Tools\axis2c\include/platforms/windows/axutil_windows.h:221:5: warning: "/*" within comment
E:\dev\c\Math\adb_addOperator.c: In function 'adb_addOperator_serialize_obj':
E:\dev\c\Math\adb_addOperator.c:574: warning: format '%I32d' expects type 'long int', but argument 3 has type 'int'
E:\dev\c\Math\adb_addOperator.c:640: warning: format '%I32d' expects type 'long int', but argument 3 has type 'int'
mingw32-g++.exe -LC:\Tools\axis2c\lib -LE:\dev\CodeBlocks\MinGW\lib  -o bin\Debug\Math.exe obj\Debug\adb_addOperatorResponse.o obj\Debug\axis2_extension_mapper.o obj\Debug\axis2_stub_MathService.o obj\Debug\main.o obj\Debug\adb_addOperator.o   -laxiom -laxutil -laxis2_engine -laxis2_parser  
obj\Debug\adb_addOperatorResponse.o: In function `adb_addOperatorResponse_create':
E:/dev/c/Math/adb_addOperatorResponse.c:58: undefined reference to `_imp__axutil_error_set_error_number'
E:/dev/c/Math/adb_addOperatorResponse.c:58: undefined reference to `_imp__axutil_error_set_status_code'
E:/dev/c/Math/adb_addOperatorResponse.c:64: undefined reference to `_imp__axutil_strdup'
E:/dev/c/Math/adb_addOperatorResponse.c:67: undefined reference to `_imp__axutil_qname_create'
obj\Debug\adb_addOperatorResponse.o: In function `adb_addOperatorResponse_free_obj':
E:/dev/c/Math/adb_addOperatorResponse.c:139: undefined reference to `_imp__axutil_error_set_error_number'
E:/dev/c/Math/adb_addOperatorResponse.c:139: undefined reference to `_imp__axutil_error_set_status_code'
E:/dev/c/Math/adb_addOperatorResponse.c:139: undefined reference to `_imp__axutil_error_set_status_code'
E:/dev/c/Math/adb_addOperatorResponse.c:150: undefined reference to `_imp__axutil_qname_free'
obj\Debug\adb_addOperatorResponse.o: In function `adb_addOperatorResponse_deserialize_obj':
E:/dev/c/Math/adb_addOperatorResponse.c:209: undefined reference to `_imp__axutil_error_set_error_number'
E:/dev/c/Math/adb_addOperatorResponse.c:209: undefined reference to `_imp__axutil_error_set_status_code'
E:/dev/c/Math/adb_addOperatorResponse.c:209: undefined reference to `_imp__axutil_error_set_status_code'
E:/dev/c/Math/adb_addOperatorResponse.c:215: undefined reference to `_imp__axiom_node_get_next_sibling'
E:/dev/c/Math/adb_addOperatorResponse.c:213: undefined reference to `_imp__axiom_node_get_node_type'
E:/dev/c/Math/adb_addOperatorResponse.c:227: undefined reference to `_imp__axiom_node_get_data_element'
E:/dev/c/Math/adb_addOperatorResponse.c:228: undefined reference to `_imp__axiom_element_get_qname'
E:/dev/c/Math/adb_addOperatorResponse.c:229: undefined reference to `_imp__axutil_qname_equals'
E:/dev/c/Math/adb_addOperatorResponse.c:232: undefined reference to `_imp__axiom_node_get_first_child'
E:/dev/c/Math/adb_addOperatorResponse.c:237: undefined reference to `_imp__axutil_qname_to_string'
E:/dev/c/Math/adb_addOperatorResponse.c:237: undefined reference to `_imp__axutil_qname_to_string'
E:/dev/c/Math/adb_addOperatorResponse.c:260: undefined reference to `_imp__axiom_node_get_next_sibling'
E:/dev/c/Math/adb_addOperatorResponse.c:258: undefined reference to `_imp__axiom_node_get_node_type'
E:/dev/c/Math/adb_addOperatorResponse.c:264: undefined reference to `_imp__axiom_node_get_data_element'
E:/dev/c/Math/adb_addOperatorResponse.c:265: undefined reference to `_imp__axiom_element_get_qname'
E:/dev/c/Math/adb_addOperatorResponse.c:268: undefined reference to `_imp__axutil_qname_create'
E:/dev/c/Math/adb_addOperatorResponse.c:272: undefined reference to `_imp__axutil_qname_equals'
E:/dev/c/Math/adb_addOperatorResponse.c:274: undefined reference to `_imp__axutil_qname_equals'
E:/dev/c/Math/adb_addOperatorResponse.c:280: undefined reference to `_imp__axiom_element_get_text'
E:/dev/c/Math/adb_addOperatorResponse.c:298: undefined reference to `_imp__axutil_qname_free'
E:/dev/c/Math/adb_addOperatorResponse.c:308: undefined reference to `_imp__axutil_qname_free'
E:/dev/c/Math/adb_addOperatorResponse.c:317: undefined reference to `_imp__axutil_qname_free'
obj\Debug\adb_addOperatorResponse.o: In function `adb_addOperatorResponse_serialize_obj':
E:/dev/c/Math/adb_addOperatorResponse.c:392: undefined reference to `_imp__axutil_error_set_error_number'
E:/dev/c/Math/adb_addOperatorResponse.c:392: undefined reference to `_imp__axutil_error_set_status_code'
E:/dev/c/Math/adb_addOperatorResponse.c:392: undefined reference to `_imp__axutil_error_set_status_code'
E:/dev/c/Math/adb_addOperatorResponse.c:395: undefined reference to `_imp__axutil_hash_make'
E:/dev/c/Math/adb_addOperatorResponse.c:398: undefined reference to `_imp__axiom_namespace_create'
E:/dev/c/Math/adb_addOperatorResponse.c:401: undefined reference to `_imp__axutil_strdup'
E:/dev/c/Math/adb_addOperatorResponse.c:401: undefined reference to `_imp__axutil_hash_set'
E:/dev/c/Math/adb_addOperatorResponse.c:404: undefined reference to `_imp__axiom_element_create'
E:/dev/c/Math/adb_addOperatorResponse.c:407: undefined reference to `_imp__axiom_element_set_namespace'
E:/dev/c/Math/adb_addOperatorResponse.c:411: undefined reference to `_imp__axiom_data_source_create'
E:/dev/c/Math/adb_addOperatorResponse.c:412: undefined reference to `_imp__axiom_data_source_get_stream'
E:/dev/c/Math/adb_addOperatorResponse.c:414: undefined reference to `_imp__axutil_hash_get'
E:/dev/c/Math/adb_addOperatorResponse.c:418: undefined reference to `_imp__axutil_hash_set'
E:/dev/c/Math/adb_addOperatorResponse.c:420: undefined reference to `_imp__axiom_namespace_create'
E:/dev/c/Math/adb_addOperatorResponse.c:420: undefined reference to `_imp__axiom_element_declare_namespace_assume_param_ownership'
E:/dev/c/Math/adb_addOperatorResponse.c:436: undefined reference to `_imp__axutil_strlen'
E:/dev/c/Math/adb_addOperatorResponse.c:436: undefined reference to `_imp__axutil_strlen'
E:/dev/c/Math/adb_addOperatorResponse.c:441: undefined reference to `_imp__axutil_strlen'
E:/dev/c/Math/adb_addOperatorResponse.c:441: undefined reference to `_imp__axutil_strlen'
E:/dev/c/Math/adb_addOperatorResponse.c:458: undefined reference to `_imp__axutil_strcmp'
Process terminated with status 1 (0 minutes, 9 seconds)
50 errors, 9 warnings
```

Form what @MikeKinghan tried to teach me, I understand the meaning of Linker commands now, and I see that the Linker is set correctly this time. but why can't it compile properly?

Comment: Probably too late to be any help - didn't notice the question. If not, are you building with 32-bit ir 64-bit MinGW?

Comment: @MikeKinghan I'm building with 64-bit MinGW .

Comment: Please build your project as is now and post the complete build log from Code::Blocks. You'll find it under the **Build log** tab in the bottom pane of the IDE, *not* the **Build messages** tab. I can build your project without difficulty but if I can't' see your build log I can't be sure that the way I build it solves the problems that prevent you from building it. Post it in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your project contains 5 source files, which each has to be successfully compiled, and then all
need linked together, along with some `axis2c` DLLs, to build your program.

Let's look at your build log.

There is a compile command for each of the 5 source files:

```
mingw32-gcc.exe -Wall  -g    -IC:\Tools\axis2c\include -IE:\dev\CodeBlocks\MinGW  -c E:\dev\c\Math\adb_addOperatorResponse.c -o obj\Debug\adb_addOperatorResponse.o
...
mingw32-gcc.exe -Wall  -g    -IC:\Tools\axis2c\include -IE:\dev\CodeBlocks\MinGW  -c E:\dev\c\Math\axis2_extension_mapper.c -o obj\Debug\axis2_extension_mapper.o
...
mingw32-gcc.exe -Wall  -g    -IC:\Tools\axis2c\include -IE:\dev\CodeBlocks\MinGW  -c E:\dev\c\Math\axis2_stub_MathService.c -o obj\Debug\axis2_stub_MathService.o
...
mingw32-gcc.exe -Wall  -g    -IC:\Tools\axis2c\include -IE:\dev\CodeBlocks\MinGW  -c E:\dev\c\Math\main.c -o obj\Debug\main.o
...
mingw32-gcc.exe -Wall  -g    -IC:\Tools\axis2c\include -IE:\dev\CodeBlocks\MinGW  -c E:\dev\c\Math\adb_addOperator.c -o obj\Debug\adb_addOperator.o
...
```

and then there is a link command:

```
mingw32-g++.exe -LC:\Tools\axis2c\include -LE:\dev\CodeBlocks\MinGW\lib  -o bin\Debug\Math.exe obj\Debug\adb_addOperatorResponse.o obj\Debug\axis2_extension_mapper.o obj\Debug\axis2_stub_MathService.o obj\Debug\main.o obj\Debug\adb_addOperator.o   -laxiom -laxutil -laxis2_engine -laxis2_parser
...
```

Copy/paste these commands out somewhere where you can see them from end to end.

In all of the places where I have put '...', the compiler or linker has emitted some complaint about your program.

All of the diagnostics emitted by the 5 compile commands are *warnings*. Whatever is not right, it doesn't actually stop the compiler from compiling the source
file (`.c`) into an object file (`.o`). If there had been any compilation *errors* in any `.c` file, then the compiler would not have been able to create the `.o` file,
and the build would have stopped without attempting to link the program, because linking it when some object files are missing would be futile.

This does *not* mean you don't have to bother about the compiler warnings. They might be warnings about possible *bugs* in your program, *and some of them are*.
So you'll need to fix them.

The link command has *failed*. You have no program, which is your top problem.

In order to make sense of compiler and linker diagnostics, and be able to fix them yourself, you need to understand what the compiler and linker commands mean.

We can see that the toolchain Code::Blocks is driving for you is the MinGW project's 32-bit Windows port of [GCC (The GNU Compiler Collection)](https://gcc.gnu.org/).
GCC is the daddy of C/C++ programming toolchains: it's supported for every operating system and every processor; it's used in every application domain.
It's completely independent of any of the numerous IDEs that you can get to drive it, and all of those IDEs (Eclipse, Code::Blocks, KDevelop, CodeLite, Anjuta,
Dev-C++, etc.) come to you with the implicit assumption that you understand compiling and linking with GCC. At least, none of them can *save you* from having
to understand compiling and linking with GCC.

Before going any further then, the life-lesson of all this is going to be: *Kick away your IDE for a while. Learn about building programs with GCC, itself.*
Then it will be obvious how to do it with your IDE.

All of your compile commands are executed by `mingw32-gcc.exe`. That's the GCC tool-driver, in its *C compiler* "posture". If you look in the directory where it's installed,
maybe `C:\MinGW\bin`, you'll see also programs `gcc.exe`, `g++.exe`, plus those two with the prefix `mingw32-`. All of these programs
are the GCC tool driver, in different "postures" adapted to different roles.

Your link command is executed by `mingw32-g++.exe`. That's the GCC tool-driver again, in its *C++ linker* "posture". It may seem puzzling that Code::Blocks
by default configures the *C++* linker to link *C* programs. It does that because C++ linkage works for programs that are all C, all C++, or a mixture of the two.
But C linkage won't work for C++ programs.

Whatever "posture" is suggested by the name, the GCC tool driver figures out what needs to be done by inspecting the options on its commandline and the file extensions
of the files that are passed to it. So it tries to compile each of your `.c` source files as C *because* they are `.c` files.
If they were `.cpp` files then it would try to compile them as C++. Once it figures out what it do, it delegates the work to an appropriate specialized tool -
C compiler, C++ compiler, assembler, linker.

Here's what each of your compile commands means:

- `-Wall` => Enable all warnings
- `-g` => Generate debugging information in the object file.
- `-IC:\Tools\axis2c\include` => Search for non-standard header files in `C:\Tools\axis2c\include`
- `-IE:\dev\CodeBlocks\MinGW` => Also search for non-standard header files in `E:\dev\CodeBlocks\MinGW`
- `-c` => Just compile; don't link
- `E:\dev\c\Math\some_filename.c` => Compile this file.
- `-o obj\Debug\some_filename.o` => Output the object file `obj\Debug\some_filename.o`

And here's what your link command means:

- `-LC:\Tools\axis2c\include` => Search for non-standard libraries (`.lib`, `.a`, `.dll`) in `C:\Tools\axis2c\include`
- `-LE:\dev\CodeBlocks\MinGW\lib` => Also search for non-standard libraries in `E:\dev\CodeBlocks\MinGW\lib`
- `-o bin\Debug\Math.exe` => Output the executable `bin\Debug\Math.exe`
- `obj\Debug\adb_addOperatorResponse.o` => Link this object file
- `obj\Debug\axis2_extension_mapper.o` => Also link this object file
- `obj\Debug\axis2_stub_MathService.o` => Also link this object file
- `obj\Debug\main.o` => Also link this object file
- `obj\Debug\adb_addOperator.o` => Also link this object file
- `-laxiom` => Link the libary `axiom.dll` or failing that, `axiom.lib` or `libaxiom.a`, wherever it is first found in the specified linker
  search directories (`-L`), or failing that in the linker's standard directories.
- `-laxutil` => Link the libary `axutil.dll` or failing that, `axutil.lib` or `libaxutil.a`, etc...
- `-laxis2_engine` => Link the libary `axis2_engine.dll` or failing that, `axis2_engine.lib` or `libaxis2_engine.a`, etc...
- `-laxis2_parser` => Link the libary `axis2_parser.dll` or failing that, `axis2_parser.lib` or `libaaxis2_parser.a`, etc...

You might wonder how the tool-driver knows that the link command *is* a link command, and not perhaps a C++ compile command?
It knows there is no compiling to do because none of the input files *can be compiled*. They are all object files (`.o`).
And it knows it is supposed to *link* them because it hasn't been told *not* to link them: the `-c` option is absent.

You linkage failed because:

```
e:/dev/codeblocks/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.4.1/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -laxiom
```

`ld.exe` is the linker itself: the specialized tool that the GCC tool driver invokes when there is linking to be done.
It can't find your `axiom` library in any of the linker search directories you specified (`-L`), nor, of course, in
any of the standard search directories.

Now that you understand the meaning of your link command, it will be easy for you to see what's wrong. The linker
search directories that you specified are:

```
C:\Tools\axis2c\include
E:\dev\CodeBlocks\MinGW\lib
```

and your `axis2c` libraries (`axiom.dll` etc) aren't in either of those places. `C:\Tools\axis2c\include`
is the same place where you told the *compiler* to search for the `axis2c` *header files*: you have:

```
-IC:\Tools\axis2c\include
```

So if that's where the `axis2c` header files are, then the libraries, I guess, are in `C:\Tools\axis2c\lib`. Have a look.
Assuming that's right, then in the C::B IDE you need to delete the wrong `C:\Tools\axis2c\include` from **Search directories** -> **Linker**
for your project and replace it with the correct `C:\Tools\axis2c\lib` Leave `C:\Tools\axis2c\include` in **Search directories** -> **Compiler**,
because that is correct.

**Continued for OP's further issues**

I believe that your `axis2c` libraries and header files originated from [Apache's Axis2/C download page](http://axis.apache.org/axis2/c/core/download.cgi)
from the archive `axis2c-bin-1.6.0-win32.zip`.

This release suffers from a [bug in its header files](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AXIS2C-1493) that causes the linkage errors
you are seeing with the MinGW32 toolchain.

This bug does not affect [Google's release of Axis2/C](https://code.google.com/p/axis2c-unofficial/) that I referred you to
in my first answer to this question. At that time you said that you were building with 64-bit MinGW, but it has since
become clear that you are building with 32-bit MinGW. In that case, you should download [Google's 32-bit build Axis2/C](https://code.google.com/p/axis2c-unofficial/downloads/detail?name=axis2c-unofficial-mingw-7acae470da50.7z)

Unzip the archive with 7-Zip and rename the unzipped folder from `axis2c` to `axis2c-x86-google`, to make clear what it is, then copy it somewhere convenient
for your development. Let's say you put it at `C:\Tools\axis2c-x86-google`.

Then in the C::B IDE, in **Search directories** -> **Compiler**, change:

```
C:\Tools\axis2c\include
```

to:

```
C:\Tools\axis2c-x86-google\include\axis2-1.6.0
```

and in **Search directories** -> **Linker**, change:

```
C:\Tools\axis2c\lib
```

to:

```
C:\Tools\axis2c-x86-google\lib
```

The library that is called `axiom.dll` in the Apache release is called `axis2_axiom.dll` in Google's release. Therefore
in your **Linker settings** -> **Other linker options**, change:

```
-laxiom
```

to:

```
-laxis2_axiom
```

Your program then links successfully (for me).

**Continued again**

Per your comments, the program now fails to load at runtime with the error:

```
The procedure entry point axis2_callback_create could not be located in the dynamic link library
```

This means the correct DLL providing `axis2_callback_create` is not found at runtime.

You say:

> I also added the "lib" to path environment. and also added the lib dll files to "C:\Windows\SysWOW64"

- Do one or the other, not both.
- Depending on what you did to add the Axis2/C library directory to the `PATH`, it may have had no effect.

  - If you did this in a shell (command prompt) window that was not the very same one in which your tried to run your
    program, then it will have had no effect, since environment settings that you make in a shell apply only to
    processes launched in the same shell.
  - If you did this by modifying the `PATH` environment variable in Advanced System Settings then that will have
    no effect on a shell already open in which you tried to run your program. You would need save the Advanced System Settings
    and then try again to run your program in a new shell.

I am able to start your program without DLL errors in all of the following ways:

- With all of the files `C:\Tools\axis2c-x86-google\lib\*.dll` located in the same directory with `Math.exe`
- With all of the files `C:\Tools\axis2c-x86-google\lib\*.dll` located instead in `C:Windows\SysWOW64`
- In a shell window in which I have previously run: `set PATH=%PATH%;C:\path\to\my\axis2c-x86-google\lib`
- In a new shell after I have added `C:\path\to\my\axis2c-x86-google\lib` to the `PATH` environment
  variable in Advanced System Settings.

If none of them works for you then I'm afraid the problem is beyond me :(

Comment: I made a mistake putting "C:\Tools\axis2c\include" in the **Search directories>Linker** . now I have fixed it. but still can't compile the project. I keep getting **Undefined Reference ...** .
I posted the build log in the question. Thanks for helping me.

Comment: @SarahAziziyan Last instalment of this answer solves this issue

Comment: Hi. I just saw your answer. Thank you very much. it kind of solved the problem, and I could build the project without any problem. but when I run it I get this message: **The procedure entry point axis2_callback_create could not be located in the dynamic link library ..."**

Comment: I also added the "lib" to path environment. and also added the lib dll files to "C:\Windows\SysWOW64".  but still get the error.

Comment: I did what you said but still get that error. I'll try to run it in another computer. I'll keep you posted. It was very nice of you to answer me in such great details. Thank you very much.

Comment: Sorry there's been no solution. You're having rotten luck with this.

Comment: I can't believe, I finally could compile and run the program. I added the ../lib to path environment but it didn't work(I don't know why). Then I tried another way, I opened cmd and executed the command  **set PATH=%PATH%;C:\axis2c-x86-google\lib** it still didn't work. This time I copied all dll files in ../lib to **C:\Windows\SysWOW64** it finally worked. It was really a great help. I can't thank you more.

Answer (score 0):

I don't follow the reasoning behind the steps you have taken and don't
have any concrete data about what you did, so this is an answer "from first principles".

If you want to link a DLL `foo.dll` with your program using *Microsoft's* linker (which you are *not* doing) you cannot
pass `foo.dll` directly to the linker. As you know, you must instead pass an *import* library, `foo.lib`, which is
a small static library of "stubs" representing the functions that are exported by `foo.dll`. At runtime,
the program loader scans these stubs and (if possible) replaces them with matching references to
to exported functions that it finds by searching available DLLs according to [the Windows DLL Search Path](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7d83bc18.aspx)

If you want to link `foo.dll` with your program using the MinGW GNU linker (which you *are* doing), no
import library `foo.lib` is necessary. This linker can link `foo.dll` directly. There is no reason for you to
do otherwise.

To link `foo.dll` directly with your program using the MinGW GNU linker, the linker, of course,
must be able to find `foo.dll` at linktime by the the rules that it follows to find libraries, whether static or
dynamic. And just as with Microsoft's linker, successful linkage of a DLL does not guarantee that the DLL
will also be found at *runtime* by the program loader. The program loader searches for DLLs according to
the the Windows DLL Search Path: it doesn't know or care which linker you used to link your program. You
have to make sure that the linker finds the DLL at linktime, and then you need to make sure that the program
loader will find it at runtime.

How do you tell the MinGW linker to link `foo.dll` directly? You just follow the rules for passing libraries to
the linker, as [documented here](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/specify_the_libraries_for_the_linker_to_use).

But before you can attempt that there is one other basic condition that has to be satisfied. *You
can't link a 32-bit DLL with a 64-bit program, or vice versa*. You say you are building with 64-bit MinGW;
so by default it will build 64-bit executables, and if your are building a 64-bit `.exe` then you must link it with 64-bit builds of the `axis2c` DLLs.

I don't know where you got your `axis2c` libraries, but if you downloaded Apache's v1.6.0 binary archive
then you have got 32-bit DLLs.

You could tell your 64-bit MinGW to build a 32-bit `.exe`, but you'd probably prefer to link it with 64-bit `axis2c` DLLs. Fortunately,
a 64-bit build is provided by Google. Download it from [here](https://code.google.com/p/axis2c-unofficial/). The 64-bit archive is
[x86_64-wsdk7.1-r7acae470da50.7z](https://code.google.com/p/axis2c-unofficial/downloads/detail?name=axis2c-unofficial-x86_64-wsdk7.1-r7acae470da50.7z).
Download it somewhere convenient; extract it with `7-Zip`, and then I suggest you rename the extracted folder to something that will identify it
clearly, like `axis2c-x86_64-google`.

Now, I'll compile and link at the command prompt an example `axis2c` program, following the linker's rules for finding libraries.
The program I'll build is one of the sample programs provided in the Apache package: `axis2c-bin-1.6.0-win32\samples\src\client\echo`.
I picked it at random: it contains only one source file, which is `echo.c`.  My toolchain is 64-bit GCC 4.9.2. I have my 64-bit `axis2c` package downloaded, unzipped and renamed as
`C:\develop\stackoverflow\axis2c-x86_64-google`

I open a command prompt in the `echo` directory and enter:

```
gcc -IC:\develop\stackoverflow\axis2c-x86_64-google\include\axis2-1.6.0 -c echo.c -o echo.o
```

I'm telling `gcc` to compile `echo.c` to `echo.o`, and that it should search for non-standard header files
in `C:\develop\stackoverflow\axis2c-x86_64-google\include\axis2-1.6.0`. (To understand basically how to compile and
link programs with GCC, I suggest you read [this tutorial](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~beechung/ref/gcc-intro.html)).

I get a compiler warning:

> warning Please include winsock2.h before windows.h

but it's not an *error* so I'm not going to worry about it for the purposes of this demonstration.

Next, I want to link the `echo.o` I've just built with the `axis2c` DLLs that it requires to
make a program called `axis2c-echo.exe`. So I enter:

```
gcc -o axis2c-echo.exe echo.o  -LC:\develop\stackoverflow\axis2c-x86_64-google\lib  -laxiom -laxutil -laxis2_engine -laxis2_parser
```

I'm telling `gcc` that besides the object file `echo.o`, the program needs to link the libraries (`-l`) `axiom`, `axutil`, `axis2_engine` and `axis2_parser`,
and that the linker should look for non-standard libraries in `C:\develop\stackoverflow\axis2c-x86_64-google\lib`.

Notice that I don't need to tell the linker that, say, the `axiom` library is `axiom.dll` and not `axiom.lib` or `libaxiom.a`. `-laxiom` tells the
linker to look for *any* of these in a given search directory and if it happens to finds a dynamic library (`axiom.dll`) it will prefer it to any static
library `axiom.lib` or `libaxiom.a`. In `C:\develop\stackoverflow\axis2c-x86_64-google\lib` it will in fact find both `axiom.dll` and `axiom.lib`,
and prefer the former; but you don't need to care.

The linkage command succeeds, so now I have a program, `axis2c-echo.exe` in the same directory. I'll run it:

```
axis2c-echo
```

But I can't. I just get a Windows error dialog that says:

> This program can't start because axiom.dll is missing from your computer. Try reinstalling the program to fix this error.

The problem is that `axiom.dll` was linked from `C:\develop\stackoverflow\axis2c-x86_64-google\lib`, which is not one of the
places where the program loader searches for DLLs at runtime.

Now if I planned to be regularly running `axis2c` programs on my computer, I would solve this by installing the 64-bit `axis2c` DLLs
in `C:\Windows\SysWOW64`, because 64-bit Windows always searches for DLLs there. But I don't plan to do that, so instead I'll just
temporarily add `C:\develop\stackoverflow\axis2c-x86_64-google\lib` to the Windows DLL Search Path. The last stop on the Windows DLL Search Path
is: *The directories listed in the PATH environment variable*. So at my command prompt I'll enter:

```
set PATH=%PATH%;C:\develop\stackoverflow\axis2c-x86_64-google\lib
```

and then run `axis2c-echo` again. This time, the output is:

> AXIS2C_HOME is not set - log is written to . dir
>   Using endpoint : http://localhost:9090/axis2/services/echo
>   Error creating service client, Please check AXIS2C_HOME again

Now the program *itself* is complaining, but that's good enough for me! It has compiled, linked, loaded,
produced some output and finished gracefully.

It's probably obvious now how you would set up a Code::Blocks project to build this same program:

- Create a C-language console project in the `echo` directory.
- Delete the default `main.c` source file from the project
- Add the single source file `echo.c` to the project.
- In the project's **Build options** -> **Search directories** -> **Compiler**, add `C:\develop\stackoverflow\axis2c-x86_64-google\include\axis2-1.6.0`
  (or `path\to\your\axis2c-1.6.0\header-files`)
- In the project's **Build options** -> **Search directories** -> **Linker**, add `C:\develop\stackoverflow\axis2c-x86_64-google\lib`
  (or `path\to\your\axis2c-1.6.0\libraries`)
- In the project's **Build options** -> **Linker settings** -> **Other linker options**, add `-laxiom -laxutil -laxis2_engine -laxis2_parser`

This isn't the only way you could successfully configure this project in C::B, but it corresponds to the way someone would normally build the
project at the command prompt, and means that the toolchain commands that C::B executes will be concise and normal-looking.

If you follow these steps to build the example `echo` project you shouldn't have much difficulty successfully configuring your own project.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. I'm trying to do every step that you have suggested. I'll tell you the results.

Comment: Hi I tried to do what you said, but I'm still not able to compile my project in CodeBlocks. It says: "Undefined reference to ... " I included my project in this [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/b8ivo6m5xrwcocs/Math.rar?dl=0) . I'd really appreciate it if you take a look.
I'm not an expert in C. so sorry if I'm bothering you with asking nonsense questions.

Comment: Please build your project as is now and post the complete build log from Code::Blocks. You'll find it under the **Build log** tab in the bottom pane of the IDE, *not* the **Build messages** tab. I can build your project without difficulty but if I can't' see your build log I can't be sure that the way I build it solves the problems that prevent you from building it. Post it in the question.

Comment: I edited the question and I posted the build log.
PS : I do not have enough reputation to vote up your answer but if I had I'd voted it +100. you've been a great help to me. Thank you very much.